# Having multiple store views share the same order increment_id number range

Tags: configuration, magento-1, multistore

Can Magento be configured in a way, that multiple store views of the same website can **share the same** order `increment_id` number range? And if so, how?

For example, with a multistore setup like this in `core_store`:

```
store_id        code    website_id    group_id
       0       admin             0           0
       1       alpha             1           1
       2       bravo             2           2
       3     charlie             2           2
```

Now a new store view `delta` is added:

```
store_id        code    website_id    group_id
       4       delta             1           1
```

Assuming `alpha`'s last order increment id currently is 1000123, how to achieve:

```
next sell    order number
    alpha         1000124
    delta         1000125
    delta         1000126
    alpha         1000127
```

Same question goes for multiple store views sharing the same invoice `increment_id` number range, and/or sharing the same creditmemo `increment_id` number range.

Does Magento support this out-of-the-box?

Comment: With guidance from @alessandro-ronchi I implemented the solution like this. https://gist.github.com/mblarsen/012dce6f55ad5d442f41e9157e74530e works great for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd imagine that this would be quite difficult.  Increment id's are stored in the `eav_entity_store` table and unsurprisingly each store has it's own entry which is updated when an order (and quote, invoice etc) is created.  To get all stores to use the same incrementer you would need to somehow rewrite this logic so it used the same row in the DB.  Quite what impact this may have on other areas of the site is something else that would  need to  be considered.

Comment: I agree with Richard.

Comment: You're probably right but running this code made all my invoices follow a same number sequence `Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode('invoice')->setIncrementPerStore(false)->save()`

Answer (score 3):

You can override orders, shippings, invoices and credit memos increment model by rewriting the "eav/entity_increment_numeric" class providing custom logic in a Model of yours.

Take a look at the ancestor classes (Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Numeric and Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Abstract) in order to understand how to provide your own logic.

You can the differentiate logic between different entities by checking the $entityTypeCode parameter of the getNextId() function you will override.

Another (more invasive) way is that of specifying a different increment model for each entity type by overwriting (via install script) the value of the "increment_model" column of the "eav_entity_type" table. Personally I prefer the "rewrite" solution mentioned above.

Pay attention: increment ids have a uniqueness constraint in latest Magento versions so you can't store the same increment id for two different entities of the same type. In other words you can't have two different invoices with the same increment id.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Looked into this but I'm unable to find `getLastId()` in `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Increment_Numeric` or in any other class or interface in hierarchy. Btw, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: UPDATE: Just realized it is a property set on the `Varien_Object` from `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type`

Comment: Implemented it like this: https://gist.github.com/mblarsen/012dce6f55ad5d442f41e9157e74530e

Answer (score 2):

While digging deeper, I realized that `eav_entity_type.increment_per_store` may be helpful.

It is. But only for the case, when you want **all store views** (globally, no matter which website they're defined in) of your Magento installation to share the same order `increment_id` number range.

This doesn't solve my specific issue, but maybe it's helpful to some others, so here we go:

To activate global sharing of your order numbers, set `eav_entity_type.increment_per_store` of the order entity to `0` ,

This leads to `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type::fetchNewIncrementId()` using `store_id = 0` when loading the `eav_entity_store` record of the order entity, no matter which store view it really belongs to.

If no such record exists, Magento creates one, using `store_id` and `increment_prefix` of `0`.

```
public function fetchNewIncrementId($storeId = null)
{
    if (!$this->getIncrementModel()) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!$this->getIncrementPerStore() || ($storeId === null)) {
        /**
         * store_id null we can have for entity from removed store
         */
        $storeId = 0;
    }

    // Start transaction to run SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
    $this->_getResource()->beginTransaction();

    $entityStoreConfig = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_store')
        ->loadByEntityStore($this->getId(), $storeId);

    if (!$entityStoreConfig->getId()) {
        $entityStoreConfig
            ->setEntityTypeId($this->getId())
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->setIncrementPrefix($storeId)
            ->save();
    }

    $incrementInstance = Mage::getModel($this->getIncrementModel())
        ->setPrefix($entityStoreConfig->getIncrementPrefix())
        ->setPadLength($this->getIncrementPadLength())
        ->setPadChar($this->getIncrementPadChar())
        ->setLastId($entityStoreConfig->getIncrementLastId())
        ->setEntityTypeId($entityStoreConfig->getEntityTypeId())
        ->setStoreId($entityStoreConfig->getStoreId());

    /**
     * do read lock on eav/entity_store to solve potential timing issues
     * (most probably already done by beginTransaction of entity save)
     */
    $incrementId = $incrementInstance->getNextId();
    $entityStoreConfig->setIncrementLastId($incrementId);
    $entityStoreConfig->save();

    // Commit increment_last_id changes
    $this->_getResource()->commit();

    return $incrementId;
}
```

This should work for any entity type using the `eav/entity_increment_numeric` model, like `order`, `invoice`, `shipment` and `creditmemo`.

Be aware though, that I couldn't find any official documentation of `increment_per_store` yet. And that there's no option in the Magento backend letting you configure this.

This may or may not mean, that it's not thought to be used officially.

Use at your own risk. If your changes wreak havoc, don't blame me. You've been warned^^

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported out-of-the-box. I also wanted to do this once to have a second storeview for an A/B Test share the same increment_id from the original store.

I tried to match those 2 numbers the simple way when `checkout_submit_all_after` is fired, but felt very uncomfortable with it, so I dropped it. I guess with more storeviews and a lot of traffic this can result in a real mess so you have to dig deeper in Magentos logic.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Having a differing order/invoice/creditmemo etc... number range is quite nice, for different countries, which most often means on a store group level.

But having different number ranges on store view level is a bad thing if you use store views for different languages, which might be done in 90% of all cases.

**Luckily it is not that difficult as proposed in this thread:**

What we are going to do is we fetch the **default store view id instead of using the store view id the method is called with**. We are doing this by resolving the store group for the current store view and fetch its default store view id. Then every store view of a specific store group uses the same number range format (the one from the default store view).

Create this class:

```
class Funky_Module_Model_Entity_Type extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type
{
    /**
     * Retreive new incrementId
     *
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return string
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function fetchNewIncrementId($storeId = null)
    {
        if (!$this->getIncrementModel()) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$this->getIncrementPerStore() || ($storeId === null)) {
            /**
             * store_id null we can have for entity from removed store
             */
            $storeId = 0;
        }

        //FIX START:
        $groupId = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId)->getGroupId();
        $group =  Mage::getModel('core/store_group')->load($groupId);
        $storeId = $group->getDefaultStoreId();
        //FIX END:

        // Start transaction to run SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
        $this->_getResource()->beginTransaction();

        try {

            $entityStoreConfig = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_store')
                ->loadByEntityStore($this->getId(), $storeId);

            if (!$entityStoreConfig->getId()) {
                $entityStoreConfig
                    ->setEntityTypeId($this->getId())
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->setIncrementPrefix($storeId)
                    ->save();
            }

            $incrementInstance = Mage::getModel($this->getIncrementModel())
                ->setPrefix($entityStoreConfig->getIncrementPrefix())
                ->setPadLength($this->getIncrementPadLength())
                ->setPadChar($this->getIncrementPadChar())
                ->setLastId($entityStoreConfig->getIncrementLastId())
                ->setEntityTypeId($entityStoreConfig->getEntityTypeId())
                ->setStoreId($entityStoreConfig->getStoreId());

            /**
             * do read lock on eav/entity_store to solve potential timing issues
             * (most probably already done by beginTransaction of entity save)
             */
            $incrementId = $incrementInstance->getNextId();
            $entityStoreConfig->setIncrementLastId($incrementId);
            $entityStoreConfig->save();

            // Commit increment_last_id changes
            $this->_getResource()->commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getResource()->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }

        return $incrementId;
    }

}
```

Add this rewrite to config.xml of your module:

```
<global>
   <models>
            <eav>
                <rewrite>
                     <entity_type>Gigaset_Core_Model_Entity_Type</entity_type>
                </rewrite>
            </eav> 
    ...
```

If you have a nicer way, without having to rewrite spread the knowledge.
Have fun. Dont hack the core.

Answer (score 0):

Use on magento2.

```
SELECT * FROM `sales_sequence_meta`;
```

All sequence_table rows are used on the same increment table.
Example - 'sequence_order_1'

```
UPDATE `sales_sequence_meta` SET `sequence_table` = 'sequence_order_1'. where meta_id =??;
```

**Note:** Empty all previous quote and invoice related rows or use the highest `sequence_value` table on these tables - ( `sequence_order_0`, `sequence_order_1`, `sequence_order_2` )

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow below steps

Step-1

There is one way to share same order increment_id, invoice_id, creditmemo_id and shipment_id for all store views,

You have to modify below table records

`sales_sequence_meta`.

Here You need to change sequence_table field value,
Ex. In My case Initially it was "sequence_order_2" for store_id = 2 and I changed it to "sequence_order_1".

You need to change it for all four entities order,invoice, creditmemo and shipment.

Please review below screenshot if you have any confusion about this.
I have tested it and it is working.

[image]

Step-2
You have to modify below table records

`sales_sequence_profile`

Here You need to change prefix field value,
Ex. In My case Initially it was "2" for field meta_id in which made  changes in step-1.
So you need to change it from "2" to "1".
Please review below screenshot for more detail.

[image]